# Unwanted highlighting with Syntastic / Jedi-Vim

Tags: python, vim, pylint, syntastic, jedi-vim

I'm using Syntastic and Jedi-Vim. At the moment I'm using Syntastics features to highlight pylint errors in vim. I feel like I've come across some sort of bug as you can see in the screenshot my custom Error line highlight will show a undercurl when I've never specified it to do that and I can't find any part of vim where I can remove the undercurl from showing.

- Why is there an undercurl when I didn't want it?
- Is this behaviour part of vim's core?
- If its not, what bundle is generating this, how do I hide the undercurl?

[Screenshot of my vim setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMghO.jpg), unwanted undercurl is on lines 4-9.

Thanks.

~_vimrc

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/vimfiles/bundle/Vundle.vim/
let path='~/vimfiles/bundle'
call vundle#begin(path)

set t_Co=256

" let Vundle manage Vundle
" " required! 
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
"Bundle 'Lokaltog/powerline'
"Bundle 'Lokaltog/powerline', {'rtp': 'powerline/bindings/vim/'}
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'
"Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
"Bundle 'klen/python-mode'
Bundle 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Bundle 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Bundle 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'
"Bundle 'ervandew/supertab'
Bundle 'ciaranm/inkpot'

call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on

let g:pymode_run = 1
let g:pymode_run_bind = "<S-R>"
let g:pymode_python = 'python3' 

"
" " The bundles you install will be listed here
"
syntax enable
colorscheme solarized
set background=dark
filetype plugin indent on
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.wsgi set filetype=python

"
" Normal startup
"
set et
set nu
set ts=4
set hls
set noru
"highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=Red
"highlight CursorLine cterm=NONE ctermbg=236
"highlight Cursor ctermfg=Red ctermbg=Red cterm=NONE
"highlight Search ctermbg=Red ctermfg=White
set guicursor=n-v-c:block-Cursor
"set cursorline
set foldmethod=syntax
set shiftwidth=4
set laststatus=2
set foldlevel=0
set foldnestmax=2
set modeline
set fileencoding=UTF-8
set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ for\ Powerline:h12:cANSI
nnoremap <space> za
vnoremap <space> zc
map <S-A> :bp<cr>
map <S-Q> :bd<cr>
map <S-S> :bn<cr>
map <S-W> :ls<cr>
set guioptions-=m  "remove menu bar
set guioptions-=T  "remove toolbar
set guioptions-=r  "remove right-hand scroll bar
"map <S-Q> :ls<cr>:sleep 850m<cr><cr>
"map <S-Q> :ls<cr>
map <S-E> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
let g:pymode_virtualenv = 1
let g:pymode_breakpoint_bind = '<leader>b'
let g:pymode_rope_completion = 1
let g:pymode_rope_complete_on_dot = 1

let g:jedi#force_py_version = 3
let g:jedi#auto_close_doc = 0
let g:jedi#popup_on_dot = 1
let g:jedi#auto_vim_configuration = 0

set completeopt=menu,longest

set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
let g:syntastic_python_checkers = [ 'pylint' ]
let g:syntastic_enable_signs = 1

let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

let g:solarized_underline = 0
let g:solarized_termcolors = 256

highlight SyntasticErrorLine guifg=blue guibg=red gui=bold
highlight SyntasticWarningLine guifg=yellow guibg=red gui=bold
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
```

vim --version

```
C:\Users\Brendan>vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug 25 2014 04:20:13)
MS-Windows 32-bit console version
Included patches: 1-417
Compiled by Haroogan <Haroogan@gmail.com>
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl                +eval               +mouse              +syntax
+arabic             +ex_extra           -mouseshape         +tag_binary
+autocmd            +extra_search       +multi_byte_ime/dyn +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval       +farsi              +multi_lang         -tag_any_white
-browse             +file_in_path       -mzscheme           -tcl
++builtin_terms     +find_in_path       -netbeans_intg      -tgetent
+byte_offset        +float              +path_extra         -termresponse
+cindent            +folding            +perl/dyn           +textobjects
+clientserver       -footer             +persistent_undo    +title
+clipboard          +gettext/dyn        -postscript         -toolbar
+cmdline_compl      -hangul_input       +printer            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist       +iconv/dyn          +profile            +vertsplit
+cmdline_info       +insert_expand      +python/dyn         +virtualedit
+comments           +jumplist           +python3/dyn        +visual
+conceal            +keymap             +quickfix           +visualextra
+cryptv             +langmap            +reltime            +viminfo
+cscope             +libcall            +rightleft          +vreplace
+cursorbind         +linebreak          +ruby/dyn           +wildignore
+cursorshape        +lispindent         +scrollbind         +wildmenu
+dialog_con         +listcmds           +signs              +windows
+diff               +localmap           +smartindent        +writebackup
+digraphs           +lua/dyn            -sniff              -xfontset
-dnd                +menu               +startuptime        -xim
-ebcdic             +mksession          +statusline         -xterm_save
+emacs_tags         +modify_fname       -sun_workshop       -xpm_w32
   system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc"
 3rd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME\_exrc"
  2nd user exrc file: "$VIM\_exrc"
Dependency: python27.dll, python34.dll, msvcrt-ruby200.dll, lua52.dll, perl518.d
ll, libintl.dll, libiconv.dll, iconv.dll
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that is interested after a day of hacking around I realized that Syntastic also had a few other options to underline the particular column of text that is in error, since pylint doesn't specify a range it will only highlight the first letter.

```
highlight SyntasticWarning NONE
highlight SyntasticError NONE
```

Did the job.

Answer (score 2):

Just set option:

```
let g:syntastic_enable_highlighting = 0
```

https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/master/doc/syntastic.txt#L412